# Unable to deploy Hosted app into Firefox OS marketplace from Tomcat

Tags: firefox-os

I'm trying to deploy a hosted app into firefox marketplace. I'm using tomcat as server. When i'm submitting my manifest.webapp file, its showing me an error

"Manifests must be served with the HTTP header "Content-Type: application/x-web-app-manifest+json".

I created .htaccess file as specified in the developer site by placing this line -> "AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json .webapp". still, getting the same error.

Is it possible to serve manifest.webapp file through tomcat server? How to work around that error.? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically this should not be a problem, you might want to check if you have not disabled override features in your .htaccess. If this is your server, you might want to add the content type declaration above in the main config, instead of the .htaccess file.

Alternatively, if you do not have access to the server configuration, you might try a dynamic approach: serving the manifest-file by specifying Content-Type on the fly using the [`contentType` directive](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s1805settingcharacterencodinginjavase01.html) in the first line of your manifest code.